How and where to find Physics Layer in Godot 4.3
I watched a video about creating a 2D game and I was stumped when I had to open the Physics layer tab in the inspector. I'm using GODOT 4.3.
I tried to find the Physics layer in all the inspector tabs hoping that it was just moved, but I found nothing.

To edit your project's physics collision layers names through the editor, navigate to Project Settings -> Layer Names.
To edit a node's collision layer/mask through the editor, navigate to the node -> click on the expand option for layer/mask .
For more, including how to set these properties through code, see the documentation below.
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html#collision-layers-and-masks
